# Cross reference format

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, cross-reference, microsoft

I have a problem in the cross reference font that is appearing every time I put a cross reference like for e.g. "Table 24" within the text, it appears automatically Bold and Italic like the caption font but I want it to have a normal format like the text without each time changing its font manually... how to do that?

Comment: A cross-reference should appear like the surrounding text. Try in a new document. Same problem? Please save a sample document in a cloud location and post a share link here.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Yes I tried in a new document and it worked for Table 1 but it didn't work for Table 2. See this link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xiyODs93RUjhvWGpXA0Ee1OjaD7P0GIg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105407441572096818802&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I could not actually get your document in Word format. From what I saw, the cross-reference above the tables had the format of the cross-reference the same for both tables. The Caption for Table 2 looked different.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon oh ok. In fact, I have uploaded it on google drive as a word file ... aren't you able to download it as a word file?? If not, how can I send you the word file? The cross reference of Table 2 does not have the same font as the text around.

Comment: I was able to download it. I have no explanation. The formatting of the Caption for Table 2 was different from that for Table 1. ----- However, using a `\* CharFormat` switch should take care of the problem.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Yes it did work! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only reliable way to do this is to add a `\* Charformat` switch to the { REF } field, i.e. reveal the code so that you see something like

```
{ REF _Ref120792894 \h }
```

change it to

```
{ REF _Ref120792894 \h \* Charformat }
```

then update the field. The Charformat switch makes the field adopt the formatting of the first "run" in the field, typically the formatting of the " R" at the beginning.

Not sure of my ground here but if you apply direct formatting to the caption itself, the reference (without the Charformat switch) will take on the formatting of the caption. If you don't apply formatting, in this case at least, the reference seems to take on the formatting of the default font (of the Normal style), which in this case is Calibri font, rather than the Times New Roman font of the Caption, which I think comes from the Caption style.

It might also be possible, and if so, simpler, to redefine the default font and caption font to Times New Roman. But I haven't verified whether that fixes the problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The caption font is already putten as Times new Roman and even though Table 2 cross ref didnt appear in that font but in calibri font... any idea why? And how to fix it?

Comment: @E.s. I think it will work better if you cnage the font of the Normal Style to TNR. I did that here and I din't even have to re-execute the 2nd ref. field to see the change. But that means that if you want to use Calibri as the font for most of your document you will either need to apply it where necessary, or create suitable paragraph styles with the Calibri font and use them instead of Normal.

Comment: Thank you! Yes it worked for me... but the point is that can I do it automatically? I mean that regardless of the caption font, the cross reference should appear as the text font but it is not. I tried it and it is automatically appearing as the caption font unfortunatelly. Otherwise, I should keep on manually changing the font of each cross reference for it to work which is non practical because they are numerous.

Comment: I have changed the question above to be more clear. And I will add a link to word file

Comment: @E.s.  I cannot see an obvious way to do this automatically *in all circumstances*. AFAICS the way Word chooses the font of the REF field result means that you can always manufacture a situation where Word will display the wrong font unless you include a \\*Charformat switch (which requires manual effort). If you can avoid creating that situation, AFAICS that's the closest you'll get to "automatic". But I may well be missing an obvious solution. I regard Word's method of choosing the REF font as an error, because the choice should be "surrounding font" or "the font you can see in the Caption"

Comment: @E.s. BTW I was able to download the .docx "as is" from the Google docs site. I had a good look at the underlying XML of the document, can see roughly what Word is doing, and was able to do a number of experiments.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks for your answers!